# OctoberCMS Translate plugin redirect with hash

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

I am using OctoberCMS Translate plugin (https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-translate) and its working as per my expectations.

However, I have one custom requirement in which I am generating hash in url (i.e. http://localhost/ibis/whats-on/details#2020-sydney-international-whitewater-event - **#2020-sydney-international-whitewater-event**).

Now the thing is, when I am supposed to redirect using below code,

```
 {% for code, name in locales %}
  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" data-request="onSwitchLocale" data-request-data="locale: '{{ code }}'">
      {{ name |upper }}
  </a>
```

I am able to redirect, however, my url looses its hash tag and it becomes something like **http://localhost/ibis/fr/whats-on/details** (**fr** is my selected french language).

Here below  is my overwrite code in my layout's code tab to `onSwitchLocale` method which is  provided by **Translate plugin**.

```
use RainLab\Translate\Models\Locale as LocaleModel;
use RainLab\Translate\Classes\Translator;
use October\Rain\Router\Router as RainRouter;


function onSwitchLocale()
{
    $this->translator = Translator::instance();
    $locale = post('locale');

    if (!$locale = post('locale')) {
            return;
    }
    $this->translator->setLocale($locale);

    $pageUrl = $this->translator->withPreservedQueryString($this->translator->makeLocaleUrlFromPage($locale), $locale);
    if ($this->property('forceUrl')) {
        return Redirect::to($this->translator->getPathInLocale($pageUrl, $locale));
    }

    return Redirect::to($pageUrl);
}
```

As you can see I am trying to accomplish url redirect with hash, but I am getting error here saying

> Call to undefined method RainLab\Translate\Classes\Translator::withPreservedQueryString()

And unable to proceed this request. I researched further and found `withPreservedQueryString` has protected method and I tried various ways to execute this method but unable to do so.

So first I need to accomplish this and second I want to append that `hash` tag in my url.

Can someone guide me from here on how can I achieve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure `$this->translator` [ Translator::instance(); ] has this method there ! its just method of `LocalePicker` component.

> This is implemented code there, so use this and define your own method

```php
protected function withPreservedQueryString($pageUrl, $locale)
{
    $page = $this->getPage();
    $query = request()->query();

    /**
     * @event translate.localePicker.translateQuery
     * Enables manipulating the URL query parameters
     *
     * You will have access to the page object, the old and new locale and the URL query parameters.
     *
     * Example usage:
     *
     *     Event::listen('translate.localePicker.translateQuery', function($page, $params, $oldLocale, $newLocale) {
     *        if ($page->baseFileName == 'your-page-filename') {
     *             return YourModel::translateParams($params, $oldLocale, $newLocale);
     *         }
     *     });
     *
     */
    $translatedQuery = Event::fire('translate.localePicker.translateQuery',
                                    [$page, $query, $this->oldLocale, $locale], true);

    $query = http_build_query($translatedQuery ?: $query);

    return $query ? $pageUrl . '?' . $query : $pageUrl;
}
```

> Use it like this

```php
$pageUrl = $this->
    withPreservedQueryString(  // <- this call
        $this->translator->makeLocaleUrlFromPage($locale), 
        $locale
    );
if ($this->property('forceUrl')) {
    return Redirect::to($this->translator->getPathInLocale($pageUrl, $locale));
}
```

it should work, if any doubt please comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Do I need to add `withPreservedQueryString` inside my `translate` plugin ?

Comment: you can add it where you defined your `function onSwitchLocale()`

Comment: Its saying `Call to undefined method RainLab\Translate\Classes\Translator::makeLocaleUrlFromPage()" on line 27 of /var/www/html/ibis/storage/cms/cache/d1/b5/whatson.htm.php`

Comment: I added `withPreservedQueryString` method inside my layout file. Image Screenshot URL -  https://ibb.co/fMTrsBW

Comment: Do I need to copy `makeLocaleUrlFromPage` method as well ?

Comment: oh! i see again that method is also not of the `Translator` you need to define it, as its also fo component method `https://github.com/rainlab/translate-plugin/blob/master/components/LocalePicker.php`

Comment: I have updated my code to this - https://paste.ee/p/xhLTg and still I am getting an error saying `call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Cms\Classes\Controller' does not have a method 'property'" on line 112 of /var/www/html/ibis/modules/cms/classes/CodeBase.php`